# How to alter the behavior when clicking a button on the ribbon?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, ribbon

When a user replies to an email, I'd like to keep the action that is being performed **but** also perform an additional task (sending a call to a web service, which I've got working already separately). My problem consist of the following two item.

- I can't find the form definition for the reply-to-email appearance (I've found *Email* form, though).
- I don't know how to get to the ribbon button of that form and set *onclick* method on it.

Answer (score 1):

you can change the ribbon properties (such as adding / removing buttons, changing behavior) using the ribbon XML customization file (ms article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309639.aspx)).

Fortunately, someone has done microsoft's work for them, and came up with a visual editing tool that saves you the hassle of manually changing xml files.
I like [visual ribbon editor](http://crmvisualribbonedit.codeplex.com/), but there are several others (the msdn article contains links to them).

What you would probably want is to add an [action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328199.aspx) to the reply button, which would trigger a javascript function in your code